# Three.js no shadows on ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm creating terrain editor with three.js and i have encountered few problems.
First. Shadows renders on MeshLambertMaterial, but it wont on ShaderMaterial.
Second. How to change object's material (from lambert to shader) on runtime?
Here's demo of my editor: `http://78.62.160.169/webgl/editor/`
And source code: `http://78.62.160.169/webgl/editor/script.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LambertMaterial` is a built-in material, that's supported by the plugins. So shadow plugin supports rendering on the `LambertMaterial`, while `ShaderMaterial` is your own shader/material, that should manually enable shadow support, it's not set by the default.

Switching material: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

Comment: Ok. So what is the way to enable shadows on ShaderMaterial?

Comment: Extract the generated shadow map and mix it up within your shader.

Answer (score 0):

here is the example of ShaderMaterial with shadow and fog

https://gist.github.com/wmcmurray/6696fc95f25bbd2401d72a74e9493261

or you can also rewrite a shader from LambertMaterial or other,

make it support your own shader